# Writing to a text file with indentation

Tags: python

I am new to Python and attempting to write a Python code that would extract some data from an excel file and create a text file (to be used as a C language header file) with the extracted data.
I am able to parse the excel and extract the relevant data, but I need some guidance in writing this data to the text file in the required format.

Data Extracted from Excel looks something like this

```
parameter_name = "Colour"
parameter_value = ["0x01","0x02","0x06","0x10"] 
parameter_value_desc = ["Black","White","Red","Indigo"]
```

The extracted data is to be written to the text file in this format (Create an Enum Declaration)

```c
typedef enum Colour{Black = 0x01, 
                    White = 0x02, 
                    Red = 0x06, 
                    Indigo = 0x10};
```

How can I write to text file such that each element of the enum appears one below the another as shown above?

I have only been able to write to the file such that the enum elements are placed side by side as shown below.

```c
typedef enum Colour{Black = 0x01, White = 0x02, Red = 0x06, Indigo = 0x10};
```

But this is a problem, when we have more enum elements, in which case the text will cross the 80 char per line restriction.

This is how my Code looks

```
def write_to_file(parameter_value, parameter_value_desc, parameter_name):
    with open("out_file.h", "a") as f:
        print("typedef enum {}".format(parameter_name) + "{", file=f, end="")
        for value, desc in zip(parameter_value, parameter_value_desc):
            print("{} = 0x{}".format(str(desc), str(value)), file=f, end=",")
        print("};", file=f, end="\n")
```

Comment: `end=",\n"` should help

Comment: (1) Determine how many characters there are between beginning of the line and `{`; (2) add corresponding number of spaces in front of subsequent lines.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent may be helpful.

Comment: If you choose a style where the amount of indentation does not depend on the first line, you can skip step (1) above and use a fixed number of spaces in step (2).

Comment: mkrieger1 I cannot use the fixed indentation, so I do need to calculate it as you suggest doing in step 1. Many thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like task for `str.join`. I would do it following way:

```
parameter_name = "Colour"
parameter_value = ["0x01","0x02","0x06","0x10"] 
parameter_value_desc = ["Black","White","Red","Indigo"]
with open("out_file.h", "a") as f:
    print("typedef enum {}".format(parameter_name) + "{", file=f, end="")
    indent_size = len("typedef enum {}".format(parameter_name) + "{")
    print((",\n" + " "*indent_size).join("{} = {}".format(str(desc), str(value)) for value, desc in zip(parameter_value, parameter_value_desc)), file=f, end="")
    print("};", file=f, end="\n")
```

`out_file.h` content:

```
typedef enum Colour{Black = 0x01,
                    White = 0x02,
                    Red = 0x06,
                    Indigo = 0x10};
```

I counted how many space I have to use to get it aligned and join elements with , newline required number of space.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on [Daweo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460056/4518341), mostly trying to make the `with`-block less busy:

```
start = f'typedef enum {parameter_name}{{'
sep = ',\n' + ' '*len(start)
values = (f'{d} = {v}' for v, d in zip(parameter_value, parameter_value_desc))
with open("out_file.h", "a") as f:
    print(f'{start}{sep.join(values_fmtd)}}};', file=f)
```

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo code:

```py
for (i, value) in enumerate(values):
    if i==0:
        out = first_line
    else:
        out = " " * len(first_line)
    out += value
    if i == len(values) - 1:
        out += last_line
    else:
        out += ",\n"
    print(out)
```

where `first_line` is `typedef enum Colour{`